# Why does my TextButton that switches screens cause my application to crash?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, skin, scene2d

I'm currently trying my hand at LibGDX to create a simple game. Currently I have finished working on the main menu and have tried to program the Level Selection menu. I have the following code in my LevelSelection class but my application crashes when I try to click on the "start" button in my main menu to bring up the Level Selection menu:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;

public class LevelSelect implements Screen {

    private Stage stage;
    private TextureAtlas atlas;
    private Table table;
    private ArrayList<TextButton> buttons;
    private Skin skin;

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }

    public void initButtons(){
        buttons = new ArrayList<TextButton>();
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            TextButton b = new TextButton(("" + i),skin);
            buttons.add(b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        /*stage.getViewport().update(width, height, false);
        table.invalidateHierarchy();*/
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        stage = new Stage();

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("ui/button.pack"));
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/menuSkin.json"),atlas);

        table = new Table(skin);
        this.initButtons();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        skin.dispose();
    }

}
```

It seems that the initButtons method isn't the issue either as even without that the application crashes. The application reports no errors, rather  I get a Java Platform SE binary has stopped working issue when I click the 'start' button that loads this new screen class.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in your LevelSelect class. Please include your main menu class, since it sounds like this is where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Also include the exception stacktrace please.

Comment: There should be some stacktrace logged. Anyhow, it is weird that you didn't implement an `create()` method in your screen. You should initialize stage etc. there instead of inside show().